# Thumbnails in Blogger Theme pixelated

Tags: css, themes, blogger

For some reason, my thumbnails are being pixelated in this blogger theme.

http://www.thatonenerdblog.com/

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow isn't a Blogger customer support site, nobody will go into deep inspection mode for you and fix your problems.

However, if you try and tell us what the problem is in details, what you've tried so far, where you think the problem is coming from etc, we'll be glad to help.